Unable to insert data into in memory h2 table for tests when using multiple data sources
I've recently had to add a second mysql data source to my spring app, and have it all working following various guides like https://scattercode.co.uk/2016/01/05/multiple-databases-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-jpa/. However, now my acceptance tests are failing because my previously working test.sql script is failing with a org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "EXAMPLETABLE" not found; SQL statement: DELETE FROM exampletable error message.
The datasource config for the database I'm attempting to insert test data into:
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "exampleEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "exampleTransactionManager",
        basePackages = {"com.companyName.exampleapi.repository.example"}
)
public class ExampleDataSourceConfig {

    @Bean(name = "exampleTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager exampleTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("exampleEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory exampleEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(exampleEntityManagerFactory);
    }

    @Bean(name = "exampleEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean exampleEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder exampleEntityManagerFactoryBuilder, @Qualifier("exampleDataSource") DataSource exampleDataSource) {

        return exampleEntityManagerFactoryBuilder
                .dataSource(exampleDataSource)
                .packages("com.companyname.exampleapi.model.entity.example")
                .persistenceUnit("example")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "exampleDataSource")
    public DataSource exampleDataSource(ExampleDataSourceProperties exampleDataSourceProperties) {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(exampleDataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName());
        dataSource.setUrl(exampleDataSourceProperties.getUrl());
        dataSource.setUsername(exampleDataSourceProperties.getUsername());
        dataSource.setPassword(exampleDataSourceProperties.getPassword());

        return dataSource;
    }
}


Which uses the following entity model:
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Schema
@Entity
@Table(name="exampletable")
public class ExampleTableRecord {
    private String exampleField1;
    private String exampleField2;

}

I have the following in my application.yml under my test resources:
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        default_schema:
    defer-datasource-initialization: true
  datasource:
    example:
      driverClassName: 'org.h2.Driver'
      url: 'jdbc:h2:mem:EXAMPLE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1'

In my testdata.sql, I'm simply deleting from the table then inserting a record:
DELETE FROM exampletable;
INSERT INTO exampletable(exampleField1, exampleField2) VALUES ('exampleValue1','exampleValue2');


Which is then used in my acceptance test as follows:
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@Sql("/db/testdata.sql")
class ExampleControllerTests {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Test
    void givenValidRequest_whenCallingExampleEndpoint_returns200() {

        RestAssured.given()
                .contentType("application/json")
                .accept("application/json")
                .get("http://localhost:" + port + "/example/endpoint")
                .then().statusCode(200).body("status", equalTo("exampleField1"));
    }
}

The previously passing test is now failing on the sql with:
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource [db/testdata.sql]: DELETE FROM exampletable; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "EXAMPLETABLE" not found; SQL statement: DELETE FROM exampletable [42102-194]
I assume that the changes I made to make the multiple datasources work need to be handled in some fashion in my test resources, but can't find examples to follow.  I'm relatively new to spring, and still learning how everything works under the hood.
I also didn't include the code for my second data source, but it follows the same patterns as this one.  Although I don't need to insert test data into that second data source, so I only need to get the previously passing tests working again.
Thanks!

(1) your datasource:  example ,  driverClassName: 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver' , but  url: 'jdbc:h2:mem:EXAMPLE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1' (2) Driver is MySQL , URL is H2.

Wow, I knew it was something simple I was missing but not that simple. Thanks!

Hmm still getting the same error after fixing that

I ended up swapping out the test data insert to using when.thenReturns for the repositories in my acceptance tests.  Will leave this open because I am curious how to get it working though
